# Embedded Signing - Signer didn't receive the completed document

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement embedded signing in our application. I followed the steps as mentioned in the guide - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/embedding

I am able to create the envelope, generate the recipient signing URL, use that URL to sign and complete the document. But I haven't received the completed signed document to the email that I mentioned as the Signer.
Is there any additional properties that I need to specify to receive the document signed via the recipient signing URL?
What is the other way to receive the signed document in this case, Can I use webhook to receive the completed document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, webhook is the better approach for this.
in Embedded signing there are no emails going to the signer. That's the purpose. Embedding it in your app unlike remote signing where emails are sent.
Your app can receive a webhook notification from connect and retrieve the complete document.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status provide some examples. There are other resources about how to use DocuSign Connect webhook.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option for this in the esignature admin tool., `Send completion emails to embedded signers`

That setting is account-wide. So if your application is used by people in multiple accounts, you'll need to set it for each account.